# assert isinstance doesn't work as expected with collection types

Tags: python, assert

I wrote this code:

```
def func(collection_type):
assert isinstance(collection_type,(list,set))
```

then I wrote:

```
func(collection_type=set)
```

And I got AssertionError

Comment: Is there a missing `def` on the first line?

Comment: `set` is the set type, it's not an instance of a set. The assertion error is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert isinstance(collection_type,(list,set))`. This will test whether the given **instances** belongs to `(list,set)` or not. So try with instances of list or set like this,

`func(collection_type=[1, 2, 3])` or `func(collection_type={1, 2, 3})`.

In python all the classes are instances of `type` class. So if you pass the class itself like `func(collection_type=set)`. It will check for `type`, since only `(list,set)` are there, it will raise assertionError.

If you want to test with a empty set, try `func(collection_type=set())`